# HDFS and truncating file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

HDFS documentation declares that files are just appendable. So you can only append data to the end of file and can't change previously written data.

But API has truncate method where you can specify а new size of  file which must be less then its current size. Generally speaking I can use this method to change file content.

Who can explain this discrepancy? How does this method work inside?