# How to create empty files of desired size in HDFS?

Tags: file, hadoop, resize, hdfs, truncate

I am new to Hadoop and HDFS. I believe my question is somewhat related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652773/hdfs-and-truncating-file?newreg=f0fadaeda75348a3a8a4a6ddcee5a350).  Essentially, I am trying to create empty files of 10 GB size in HDFS.  The truncate command fails as specifying file size larger than the existing file size seems forbidden.  Under such circumstances, what are the alternatives?  For example, in Linux systems, one can use "truncate" command to set arbitrary file size.

Comment: Why don't you create the file with truncate and then put it in HDFS?

Comment: Do you meant creating an empty file of desired size in conventional FS using truncate and then ingesting into HDFS?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestDFSIO to create the file with the required size in HDFS directly.

Program TestDFSIO is packaged in jar file 'hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-tests.jar'. This jar comes with the hadoop installation, locate this jar and provide the path of this jar in the below command.

`hadoop jar <PATH_OF_JAR_hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-tests.jar> TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 1 -fileSize 10GB`

where "nrFiles" is Number of files and "filesize" is each file size to be generated.

File will be generated at path `/benchmarks/TestDFSIO/` in HDFS.